# How to access json Post method values in netbeans using Java

Tags: java, json, netbeans, parameters, http-post

I'm struggling with my restful webservice (Java & Netbeans 8.2)

My method looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("/usedPacking")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void setUsedPackage( ??? ) {
    ???
}
```

Actually I would like to receive a json-message as post-data like:
{"PackageID":"12345","Used":"false"}

My question is:
What do I have to replace the "???" with?

For GET-Methods it is:

```
@QueryParam("ID") String input
```

Which allows me to access the variable specified as ID by using input.

Everything I've found so far didn't quite address the problem I face..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a JAXRS webservice you can create an annotated class that maps to your json e.g.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 

@XmlRootElement 
public class Package { 
    private String packageID; 
    private Boolean used; 

    // getters and setters here
}
```

then ??? will be your class

```
public void setUsedPackage(Package package)
```

When you post your json you'll need to specify the Content-type header as application/json

Here's a jaxrs tutorial I found that may help

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/post-example/

Comment: I tried that already.
I use the RESTClient Firefox Addon to test my webservice.
But even if I select the 
Content-Type - Application/json

My server still gives me an error:
"unsupported media type" - Error Code 415

Comment: Ok, 
Now I got the reason for my error while trying this solution.

I didnt declare the variables as private and specified no Getters/Setters.
The Getters/Setters solved my problem.